# Bootstrap - Reducing gap between elements taking up 6 columns each

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an app in ruby. I'm using bootstrap4 to prototype. I have two input fields, which take up 6 columns each. Is there a way to reduce the space between the two input fields.

[image: Example]

```
div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%= f.label :apointment_cont, "Apointment" %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <%= f.date_field(:apointment_cont) %>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered making use of the `.form-control` class to style your inputs and make them take up 100% of the column width? That would leave you with just the column gutter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `no-gutters` class in the in bootstrap to avoid spacing in the columns.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :apointment_cont, "Apointment" %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.date_field(:apointment_cont) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to reduce the gap with a small spacing, you can do some css like below

```css
.reduce-space {
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 reduce-space">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 reduce-space">
    <%= f.label :apointment_cont, "Apointment" %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 reduce-space">
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 reduce-space">
    <%= f.date_field(:apointment_cont) %>
  </div>
</div>
```